# Convert if else structure into switch case in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, switch-statement

I am pretty new in programming, I am trying to convert this if else structure into Switch cases in Swift language, i appreciate your help, thanks.

here is my code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowDefinition") {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? EnglishViewController {
            if let definition = sender as? String {
                if definition == "Abstraction" {
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Abstraction"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 1"
                } else if definition == "Binary System" {
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Binary System"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 2"
                } else if definition == "Computer" {
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Computer"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 3"

                } else if definition == "Internet" {
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Internet"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 4"

                } else if definition == "Virtual Reality" {
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Virtual Reality"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 5"

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowDefinition") {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? EnglishViewController {
            if let definition = sender as? String {
                switch definition {
                case "Abstraction":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Abstraction"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 1"
                case "Binary System":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Binary System"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 2"
                case "Computer":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Computer"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 3"
                case "Internet":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Internet"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 4"
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Abstraction"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 1"
                case "Virtual Reality":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Virtual Reality"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 5"
                default:
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = ""
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check what you want to do with the `default` value, that will be hit if none of the `case` matches.

Answer (score 1):

Since `titeMsg` will contain always the `definition` string you can make the code still shorter

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "ShowDefinition" {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? EnglishViewController {
      if let definition = sender as? String {
        switch definition {
        case "Abstraction":
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 1"
        case "Binary System":
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 2"
        case "Computer":
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 3"
        case "Internet":
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 4"
        case "Virtual Reality":
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 5"
        default :
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "n/a"

        }
        destinationViewController.titleMsg = definition
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could go a step further and declare an enum of the cases

```
enum Definitions : String {
  case Abstraction, BinarySystem = "Binary System", Computer, Internet, VirtualReality = "Virtual Reality"
}
```

This saves the `default` statement, because the cases are exhaustive.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if (segue.identifier == "ShowDefinition") {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? EnglishViewController {
      if let definition = sender as? String, let definitionEnum = Definitions(rawValue:definition) {
        switch definitionEnum {
        case .Abstraction:
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 1"
        case .BinarySystem:
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 2"
        case .Computer:
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 3"
        case .Internet:
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 4"
        case .VirtualReality:
          destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 5"
        }
        destinationViewController.titleMsg = definition
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowDefinition") {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? EnglishViewController {
            if let definition = sender as? String {
                switch definition {
                case "Abstraction":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Abstraction"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 1"
                case "Binary System":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Binary System"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 2"
                case "Computer":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Computer"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 3"
                case "Internet":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Internet"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 4"
                case "Virtual Reality":
                    destinationViewController.titleMsg = "Virtual Reality"
                    destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition 5"
                default:
                    // As per your requirement
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific use case, you needn't really resort to a serial `if-else` or a `switch` block, as the test only pertains to testing whether a given `String` instance (`definition`) is equal to any member of a given list of `String`'s.

Since the `destinationViewController.titleMsg` is just given the same value as `definition` (in case of a match), and `destinationViewController.definitionMsg` is just a running number w.r.t. the indices (`+1`) of the list of `String`'s, you can capture all that logic in a single optional binding clause:

```
let validTitles = ["Abstraction", "Binary System", "Computer", "Internet", "Virtual Reality"]
let definition = "Abstraction"

if let definitionAndTitle = validTitles.enumerated().filter({$1 == definition}).first {
    print("titleMsg=\(definitionAndTitle.1)")
    print("definitionMsg=\(definitionAndTitle.0 + 1)")
}
```

Applied to your example (simply extending your existing optional binding clause)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowDefinition") {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? EnglishViewController {
            // or, better, keep this list of titles as e.g. a static
            // immutable property of your viewcontroller class, as these
            // should already be set at compile time.
            let validTitles = ["Abstraction", "Binary System",
                               "Computer", "Internet", "Virtual Reality"]
            if let definition = sender as? String, let defNum = 
                validTitles.enumerated().filter({$1 == definition}).first?.0 {
                destinationViewController.titleMsg = definition
                destinationViewController.definitionMsg = "definition \(defNum+1)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```